# Clear Select2 Listbox not clearing codebehide Listbox.text

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, listbox, jquery-select2

I have a listbox with select2 plugin:

Markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" style="top: 400px; position: absolute; z-index: 0;">
    <ContentTemplate>

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>

    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:ListBox ID="Cliente" class="select2-select" runat="server" style="width: 100%">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Value 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Vale 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

Javascript:

```
    $('.select2-select').select2({
        maximumSelectionLength: 1,
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: "Select..."
    });
    $(".select2-select").on("select2:select", function (e) {
        refreshPanel();
    });
    $(".select2-select").on("select2:unselect", function (e) {
        refreshPanel();
    });

    function refreshPanel() {
        __doPostBack("<%=UpdatePanel1.UniqueID%>", '');
    }
```

VB.NET

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    dim test as string = listbox.text
```

end sub

The panel is correctly updated and everything works, but when I clear the Listbox __postback is fired but listbox.text still contain last value.

How can I solve the problem?

----------EDIT-----------

I clear the listbox using little cross on right.

[image]

Comment: How do you clear it?

Comment: @Andrei I clear the listbox using little cross on right, as you can see in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

This could maybe work

```
test.value.clear
```

or:

```
 listBox1.Items.Clear
```

Comment: that delete all Items and I need the items. :) I think that there are some problems with the postback.